# Laravel Seeder with .sql file

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3, laravel-seeding

I want to insert 30K records to my table.
I have the .sql file for the same table and want to do with laravel seeder.

```
DB::disableQueryLog();
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents('database/seeds/sql/inv_diagnostic_fe.sql'));
```

Its only inserting 338 rows. what happening after the insertion of 338 ?
How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: no error messages. seeding was completed. but only 338 rows are inserted.

Comment: Maybe you are running out of memory? Can u give the size of your sql file? There is a similar issue at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906199/laravel-seeding-large-sql-file and it recommends to use the plain mysql command or to split the file in separate statements.

Comment: the seeder file size is 444KB

Comment: Have you tried to do a raw import through mysql and does it give the expected result? Just to make sure there is no mysql issue within the dump itself.